# Regex to extract text before and after dash (i.e '-') symbol

Tags: r, regex

I need a some R code to extract text from a character vector before the dash symbol. For instance, if I have a vector like this one:

```
vec <- ("1-2", "3-4", "5-6")
```

the first regex shoudl give me `("1", "3", "5")` and the second regex should give me `("2", "4", "6")...`

Thanks a million

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first match

```
gsub( "(.*)-(.*)", "\\1",  c( "1234-5678", "1234-5678") )
# [1] "1234" "1234"

gsub( "(.*)-(.*)", "\\1",  c("1-2", "3-4", "5-6"))
# [1] "1" "3" "5"
```

second match

```
gsub( "(.*)-(.*)", "\\2",  c( "1234-5678", "1234-5678") )
# [1] "5678" "5678"

gsub( "(.*)-(.*)", "\\2",  c("1-2", "3-4", "5-6"))
# [1] "2" "4" "6"
```